# Shortcuts with name "Uninstall <Program Name>" are not displayed in Windows 8/8.1/10

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, windows-8.1, windows-10

Using MSI installer we create application shortcuts on Windows 7, 8, 8.1 , 10 operating systems. Along with application shortcuts, we also create Uninstallation Shortcut for the program.

Path to shortcut on until Win7:
 [ProgramsMenuFolder]\CompanyName\ProductName\

Path to shortcut on until Win8/8.1/10:
 [ProgramsMenuFolder]\ProductName\

The uninstall shortcut appears on Win7 but on Win8 and above this shortcut doesn't appear for few products.

I found a blog where they say that on Win8+ shortcuts named uninstall is removed by the OS automatically. http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=378327

Could someone point out to any Microsoft documentation for this issue or even guidelines to create shortcuts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per this document 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj673981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, 
it states as below.

DON'T: Don't put shortcuts to the following items on the Start screen: (previous document says the same for StartMenu http://www.2brightsparks.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=7624)

- Uninstallers. Users can access uninstallers through the Programs item
  in the Control Panel.
- Help files. Include help topics directly in your app.
- App settings and options. Include UI to configure settings for an app
  within the app or create a Control Panel item.
- Web sites. Provide any appropriate links to information like help and
  technical support sites directly in your app.
- Wizards. Wizards and other one-time configuration tasks should be
  launched from within the app.

Other Microsoft Documentation below, it says to create shortcuts only for Programs and recommeds to use Add/Remove Programs for uninstall/repair/modify actions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742493.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The behaviour of shorcuts displayed for few products is explained in the below blog.
 http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=378327

Comment: Thank you, I was looking specifically for the links you included there! This answer is more general and useful than the question, because it also documents the reasoning behind the "we don't do that" related to uninstall shortcuts.