# Wix uninstall shortcut does not remove app completely

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, installation

I have a wix installer which copies application dlls and installs a windows service. It also creates shortcuts in programs menu (one for the app and one for uninstall process).
Shortcut for uninstall looks like the following:

```
 <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
           Name="Application"
           Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe"
           Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" />
```

Application is installed correctly, but when I try to uninstall it by the shortcut something is going wrong. All folders and files created by installer are being removed but when I enter add/remove programs menu I see entry for my application (need to remove it from context menu - it removes application completely).

What can be wrong with unistall shortcut? How to force it to remove application from the system?

All guids (for product, components) are created like this: `Guid="*"`

Comment: I guess you need to look into uninstallation log (which is created by default in your %temp% folder) and see what exactly happens during uninstallation.

Comment: MSI installs/uninstalls are transactions - they either completely work or completely fail. That's why it makes no sense that the product is partially removed. If you have Add/Remove Programs open at the time and still see your entry it could be a caching issue - I've seen those cases where you can refresh the display (with F5) and it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your answer already, but I would check both things others have mentioned:

1. Check the log file for the uninstall. I am not aware that log files are generated automatically - unless this is new in Windows 10 or something.

   - [**To make a log file for your uninstall, you can follow this procedure from installsite.org**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) (see section "***Globally for all setups on a machine***".
   - **To find a specific log**, first kick off the uninstall and let it run, then open the temp folder (Hold down <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>, tap <kbd>R</kbd>, type `%temp%` or `%tmp%` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>), now sort the files by modify date to get the latest log to the top of the list. Open it. It will have a random name.
2. If you see your product listed in `Add / Remove` after you think it is uninstalled, then the uninstall did not complete properly. Some possibilities exist.

   - Your uninstall could have **custom actions** that delete stuff on their own, and if they don't have rollback custom actions associated with them files could be missing after the failed uninstall is rolled back.
   - Re-opening the `Add / Remove` applet as **PhilDW** suggest will tell you whether the uninstall actually failed or not.
   - **Are you on a real test box or is this your development box?** During development it is not uncommon to end up with several versions of the same product installed on the same box - especially when you auto-generate your product guid and your major upgrade configuration isn't properly set up (yet). Test on a test virtual to make sure.

***Overall suggestion***: ***lose the whole uninstall shortcut!*** Such shortcuts have been undesired since the early 2000s, and I believe they are still a logo violation for Microsoft. In fact, I believe certain types of shortcuts are actually auto-hidden by the system itself. I wrote an answer on this a while back: **[Wix Uninstall Shortcut not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837398/wix-uninstall-shortcut-not-working/47849817#47849817)** (please do have a quick read).